# Почему не меняются размеры canvas-а через js?

Tags: javascript

#### Описание

Есть у меня стандартный canvas:

[image]

...которому в html/css не дал размеров. Размеры даю через js, при открытии проекта, чтобы подгонять по размерам экрана, вот так:

```js
document.getElementById("canvas_program").style.width = Program.sizePixels;
document.getElementById("canvas_program").style.height = Program.sizePixels;
```

...где `Program.sizePixels` определяется вот так:

```js
class Program
{
    static sizePixels = Math.min
    (
        document.documentElement.clientWidth - 70,
        document.documentElement.clientHeight - 150
    );
}
```

У меня оно равно 475. Но canvas даже так не реагирует.

```js
document.getElementById("canvas_program").style.width = 475;
document.getElementById("canvas_program").style.height = 475;
```

Но если к примеру менять другие параметры в том же скрипте, к примеру:

```js
document.getElementById("canvas_program").style.display = "none";
```

то всё сработает отлично:

[image]

---

#### Вопрос

Почему размеры не меняются и как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. В style размеры надо писать с `px`
2. В style размеры только для стилей, размеры холста задаются в атрибутах, а из скрипта - в свойствах.

```
canvas.width = 475
canvas.style.width = "950px"
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже второй час ломаю голову - что не так? 